# Need to group the XML with Folder name and then on sections

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

```
            <custom> 
            <section name="A">
            <element name="Folder">A11</element>
            <element name="Name">Test1</element>
            <element name="Result">Fail</element>                
            </section>
            <section name="B">
            <element name="Folder">A11</element>
            <element name="Name">Test2</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>               
            </section>
            <section name="C">
            <element name="Folder">A12</element>
            <element name="Name">Test3</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>                
            </section>
            <section name="D">
            <element name="Folder">A13</element>
            <element name="Name">Test4</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>                
            </section>
            </custom>
            <custom>             
            <section name="A">
            <element name="Folder">A12</element>
            <element name="Name">Test1</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>                
            </section>
            <section name="B">
            <element name="Folder">A12</element>
            <element name="Name">Test2</element>
            <element name="Result">Fail</element>                
            </section>
            <section name="C">
            <element name="Folder">A11</element>
            <element name="Name">Test3</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>      
            </section>
            <section name="D">
            <element name="Folder">A13</element>
            <element name="Name">Test4</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>                
            </section>
            </custom>
```

Grouping by Folder
Section Name under Folder
All Elment Name

E.g.

A11
- section name="A"
- Folder , Name , Result Value

- section name="B"
- Folder , Name , Result Value

A12
- section name="C"
- Folder , Name , Result Value

A13
- section name="D"
- Folder , Name , Result Value

--Same goes for each Custom---

Need result in below format:

```
            <root>
            <custom>
            <Folder>A11
            <section name>A
            <element name="Folder">A11</element>
            <element name="Name">Test1</element>
            <element name="Result">Fail</element> 
            </section>
            <section name="B">
            <element name="Folder">A11</element>
            <element name="Name">Test2</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>
            </section>
            </Folder>
            <Folder>A12
            <section name>C
            <element name="Folder">A12</element>
            <element name="Name">Test3</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element> 
            </section> 
            </Folder>
            <Folder>A13
            <section name="D">
            <element name="Folder">A13</element>
            <element name="Name">Test4</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>    
            </section> 
            </Folder>
            <custom>
            <custom>
            <Folder>A11
            <section name>C
            <element name="Folder">A11</element>
            <element name="Name">Test3</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element> 
            </section> 
            </Folder>
            <Folder>A12
            <section name>A
            <element name="Folder">A12</element>
            <element name="Name">Test1</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>
            </section> 
            <section name>B
            <element name="Folder">A12</element>
            <element name="Name">Test2</element>
            <element name="Result">Fail</element> 
            </section> 
            </Folder>
            <Folder>A13
            <section name="D">
            element name="Folder">A13</element>
            <element name="Name">Test4</element>
            <element name="Result">Pass</element>  
            </section> 
            </Folder>
            <custom>
            </root>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to show what you have tried already, this isn't a "give me the code" site.

Comment: The "XML" you show isn't well-formed: the `<1/2/3/image1.jpeg>` is not correct XML syntax. Before you can process anything using XSLT, it needs to be well-formed XML.

Comment: Can you show the output you except as XML (or HTML). Thank you

Comment: Updated the output as XML.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first start off with the [XSLT Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which copy across all nodes from the input document

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But you can then add a template to match `custom` element which can then be used to do the grouping of the `section` elements. In XSLT 2.0, yo can use [xsl:for-each-group](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/11/05/tr.html) for this

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="section" group-by="element[@name='Folder']">
```

Inside this, it is relatively straight-forward to create a new `folder` element, and copy across the existing `section` elements into this.

```
  <folder name="{current-grouping-key()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
  </folder>
```

Try this XSLT. Note this won't give you the XML you have shown in your question, as the XML you have shown is not well formed (`<section name>` is not valid), but it should give you the general idea.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="custom">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="section" group-by="element[@name='Folder']">
      <folder name="{current-grouping-key()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
      </folder>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element[@name='Folder']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks.
I am getting below error:

XslTransformException
---------------------
'for-each-group' is not a recognized extension element.

Comment: You've tagged this as XSLT 2.0, but are you actually using a processor that supports XSLT 2.0? What processor are you actually using to do the transformation?

Comment: How to get the processor details?

XSL header:

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

Comment: Are you using C# or VB.Net to perform the transformation?

Comment: Note that, you can use the XSLT at http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_systemproperty.asp to return what XSLT processor is being used. Note that simply changing the version to "2.0" in the XSLT won't do anything unless you are using an XSLT processor that actually supports it.